# E-bike battery-related questions

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, hardware, bms

I am a beginner and I am learning to design and develop a Battery Management System for low voltage applications like E-Bike.

I would like to build a 36 V, 10s, 2500 mAh battery pack. The knowledge that I have gathered are:

- 3.6 V lithium-ion battery has maximum charge voltage of 4.2 V and minimum of 2.5 V, for safer side 2.7 V.
- we are able to charge or discharge the 2500 mAh battery by charging or discharging 2500 mA for one hour, or 1250 mA for 2 hours. That is called battery capacity.
- when it comes to maximum output current in C rating:

  1C: an electric bike can draw (discharge) 2500 mA for 1 hour

  2C: an electric bike can draw (discharge) 5000 mA for 30 minutes

  If my understanding above is wrong, kindly correct me.

**I have received an E-bike Specification below:

Inquiry: Li-Ion battery 10S1P 36 V / 2500 mAh, for an e-bike template**

**Li-ion pack 10S1P 36 V / 2500 mAh / 90 Wh 10S1P Consisting of 10 Li-ion cells INR18650A made up according to drawing including PCM.**

**U-n = 36 V**
**I-n = 15 A ---> What is this?**

**I-pulse = 30 A briefly ---> What is this?**

**Discharge temperature range: -20 to 60° C**

**Load temperature range: 0 to 60° C**

**My doubt is: What is the maximum output current a load can draw or discharge, based on the above specifications? How to determine that?**

**And what is In and Ipuls in amps? Is this the maximum current that an E-bike can draw from the battery pack?**

Comment: *I have received a E bike Specification below:Inquiry:* if you don't know what these things are you shouldn't be taking inquiries on building things for customers who might be damaged by what you provide them.

Comment: Thank you so much for th comment sir First of all i am a student I am not building for any customer i am just learning stuffs so that it can do it as my scientific project for my academics

Comment: Safer discharge min is 3V. | You cannot charge at 1C (2500 mA) for 1 hour. Look up CCCV charging. You charge at 2500 mA (=CC)_ ONLY UNTIL Vbat = Vmax = 4.2V. You then hold at 4.2V (=CV) and current drops UNDER BATTERY CHEMISTRY CONTROL to some lower value. C/2 is usually adequate. | !n is usual max I out. Ipulse = brief Iout - usually say 10 seconds max.

Comment: Cautionary tale. My brother was part of a team that built and raced an E-bike on the Isle of Man. Fortunately it was being charged in the back of a van parked on the far side of a car park, because when it went up, only the van was lost. Large quantities of lithium cells in one place need thorough safety precautions and knowledge.

Comment: Aiaiai, why is everyone starting hobbies whithout knowledge. As the others have noted batteries can be dangerous. You not simply start builing explosives either. Do you have any knowledge about electronics especially in building a BMS? Better start with some simpler task for your academics.

Comment: @A.R.C. Thank you so much for your kind words.Sir i haven't started anything .i know its an explosive so i will not start just like that i am just gaining knowledge  with an Idea without proper knowledge i will not start the project and i have professors supervisors to validate each and every step of what iam doing. so iam just learning stuffs in that i have doubt so i am posting and LEARNING and TRYING TO GAIN KNOWLEDGE. Without proper knowledge i will not start the project . kindly help bigginers to learn stuff we are confused with google result thats why we are posting sorry Sir